# Filtering an array of objects by a number property value (range of values)

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects with a list of courses and their prices.

```
const courses = [
  { name: "Courses in England",    prices: [   0,  100] }, //1st object
  { name: "Courses in Germany",    prices: [ 500, null] }, //2nd object
  { name: "Courses in Italy",      prices: [ 100,  200] }, //3rd object
  { name: "Courses in Russia",     prices: [null,  400] }, //4th object
  { name: "Courses in China",      prices: [  50,  250] }, //5th object
  { name: "Courses in USA",        prices: [ 200, null] }, //6th object
  { name: "Courses in Kazakhstan", prices: [  56,  324] }, //7th object
  { name: "Courses in France",     prices: [null, null] }, //8th object
];
```

Here I used the filter method, which kinda works when I want to filter by the course name property.

```
const filter = courses.filter((obj) => {
  return obj.name === "Courses in England";
});
console.log(filter);
returns // { name: "Courses in England", prices: [0, 100] }
```

Here i used the for loop to get all the objects in the courses array.

```
const filter = function (arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
  }
};
filter(courses);
```

I can't figure out how to modify the Filter function to accept the prices property which has 2 number element values [100, 200] and for it to only return similar objects in the array with similar range of prices property.

My goal is as follows. For example, when I pass the number `100`
it should return:

```
{ name: "Courses in England", prices: [ 0, 100] } 
{ name: "Courses in Italy", prices: [ 100, 200] }
{ name: "Courses in Kazakhstan", prices: [  56,  324] }
```

Because these objects are >= the value 100.

Comment: Could you please explain this `only return similar objects in the array with similar range of prices property` ? If possible, provide the output you are expecting.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for feedback. I meant to return objects with the same price range property. for example, when I pass the number 100 it should return //{ name: "Courses in England",    prices: [  0,  100] } // { name: "Courses in Italy",      prices: [ 100,  200] } because both objects have the value 100. please let me know if i should explain further @zx01

Comment: @MisterJojo I didn't add _Kazakhstan_ because I was just trying to give an example of what should be returned

Comment: @MisterJojo Please I have a question. When you say `argument_value`, the `argument` is the callback function to test each element of the array and `value` is the typeof current element being processed in the array if i understood correctly

Comment: it's weird as a wording. my term argument_value is just a designation of the parameter sent in functions or methods (like here). in my code here it is called filter_Key.

Otherwise there is no callback function in my code. each return is the result produced by an array.filter() method (except the last one)

Comment: @MisterJojo Thank you very much for clarifying. Very much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that ?

usage is :

```
let answerArray = courses.filtering( argument_value )
```

- if `argument_value` is a `string`,
  the answer search all elements where `name === argument_value`
- if `argument_value` is an `array`,
  the answer search all elements where `prices array` is the same as `argument_value array`
- if `argument_value` is `null`
  the answer search all elements where the `prices array` includes a `null` value
- if `argument_value` is an integer,
  the answer search all elements where `prices array range` contains the `argument_value`

```js
const courses =
  [ { name: 'Courses in England',    prices: [   0,  100] } // 1st object
  , { name: 'Courses in Germany',    prices: [ 500, null] } // 2nd object
  , { name: 'Courses in Italy',      prices: [ 100,  200] } // 3rd object
  , { name: 'Courses in Russia',     prices: [null,  400] } // 4th object
  , { name: 'Courses in China',      prices: [  50,  250] } // 5th object
  , { name: 'Courses in USA',        prices: [ 200, null] } // 6th object
  , { name: 'Courses in Kazakhstan', prices: [  56,  324] } // 7th object
  , { name: 'Courses in France',     prices: [null, null] } // 8th object
  ];

courses.filtering = filter_Key =>  // adding a specific méthod to 
  {                               // the Object.Array (named `courses`)
  if (typeof(filter_Key) === 'string')
    return courses.filter(obj => obj.name === filter_Key)

  if (Array.isArray(filter_Key))
    return courses.filter(obj => JSON.stringify(obj.prices) === JSON.stringify(filter_Key))

  if (filter_Key===null)  
    return courses.filter(obj => obj.prices.includes(filter_Key))

  if (Number.isInteger(filter_Key))
    return courses.filter(obj => 
      {
      let [min,max] = [...obj.prices].sort((a,b)=>a-b) // expecting there is no negatives values for a price...
      if (min===null) min = max || 0
      if (max===null) max= -1

      return ( min <= filter_Key  && filter_Key <= max )
      })
 
  // anything else...
  return []    // return an empty array
  };
  
  
console.log('Courses in England ->\n' + JSON.stringify(courses.filtering( 'Courses in England' )))

console.log('\n[100, 200] ->\n' + JSON.stringify(courses.filtering( [100, 200] )))

console.log('\n100 ->\n' + JSON.stringify(courses.filtering( 100 )).replaceAll('},{','}\n,{'))

console.log('\nnull ->\n' + JSON.stringify(courses.filtering( null )).replaceAll('},{','}\n,{'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```

Comment: If we pass null, should we find the null-containing arrays? (or a course with a null name)?  Does the OP want to match both criteria at once, name *and* price?  Seems like a game of darts

Comment: @danh I think null represents the empty input field. You can search by ranges which is something like this [100, 350] or just with a number and empty input field which accounts for null which looks something like this [200, null]

Comment: @MisterJojo everything works perfectly, but we don't need to account for integers. But it is also a good practice for me to see how to approach this next time. We accounted for strings, number and integers search. Thank you very much

Comment: **->\n'**  **'\n** Please what do they signify? @MisterJojo

Comment: @nazonstack this is the carraige return  character code.  as `\t` is used for tab character

Answer (score 0):

1. To return

> the prices property which has 2 number element values

loop through all the objects and check that the value for the prices property all has the type of number and return such object.

```js
    const result = courses.filter(({ prices }) => 
          prices.every(price => typeof price === "number"))
    
    console.log(result)
    // With love @kouqhar
```

2. And

> for it to only return similar objects in the array with similar range
> of prices property

you can provide a range of number(s) and then loop through the `result` filtering the range.

E.g Range of Number between `100 - 500`
Your final code will look like the code example below, be free to type with this `(price >= 100 && price <= 500)` also the `&&` operator with `||`

```js
     const result = courses.filter(({ prices }) => 
           prices.every(price => 
              typeof price === "number" && (price >= 100 && price <= 500)))

     console.log(result)
  // With love @kouqhar
```

Comment: Good day, thank you for the feedback. With this code, I can't log in or filter with specific prices that I want to be logged in the console. I mean, I need to pass in a number value in the console for it to return objects that meets the condition of the logged in number. For example, when I pass the number 100 it should return //{ name: "Courses in England", prices: [ 0, 100] } // { name: "Courses in Italy", prices: [ 100, 200] } because both objects have the value 100. Please let me know if I should explain further @kouqhar